# Django detecting redundant migrations repetitively

Tags: python, django

#### Background

We are working in Python3.4 / Django1.8.4 and we are witnessing a strange phenomenon with respect to our `user` model, and specifically the `timezone` field of this model.

Every so often when we are making migrations the new migration file will include an operation to alter said timezone field, but all of the attributes that are included in the operation are already set to the same values that the migration is trying to assign!

There are 3 such fields and they are:

1) `default` - with the value of `"UTC"`

2) `max_length` - with the value of `30`, and

3) `choices` - a very long array of tuples containing time zone names/values.

It looks like:

```
choices=[('Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Abidjan'), ('Africa/Accra', 'Africa/Accra'), ('Africa/Addis_Ababa', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa'), ... ]
```

The migration operation always wants to set these 3 properties of the `timezone` field to the exact same 3 corresponding values, even though they are already set to such values! It is essentially a redundant, useless operation.

Sometimes when we run `makemigrations` there will be no changes to the app, *except* to this silly field!

#### Questions

1) Why is this happening?

2) How do we prevent this? It's annoying that the app thinks migrations are needed when they aren't.

#### Extra Info

While the same 3 properties of the field are always set to the exact same values, the order that they appear in the operation seems to be non-deterministic (likely because django uses unordered `dict` instances to store the data which is used to generate the migration file).

The `choices` field, as we define it in our model, is dynamically generated when the app is initially run. The (boiled-down) code looks like this:

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=32398) # Gotta accomodate those crazy south-eastern names haha
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=94823)

    # ...
    # more fields and stuff etc.
    # ...

    time_zone = models.CharField(default="UTC", choices=TIMEZONE_CHOICES, max_length=30)
```

The important part there is that `choices=TIMEZONE_CHOICES`, which is defined earlier as such:

```
import pytz
TIMEZONE_CHOICES = ()
for time_zone in pytz.common_timezones:
    TIMEZONE_CHOICES += ((time_zone, time_zone),)
```

Just including this information in case it turns out to be relevant.

Comment: What happens when you run `python manage.py makemigrations` twice? Does the second migration contain the same changes as the first one?

Comment: Nope. But a few migrations later it may be detected!

Comment: @DerekKwok WAIT ACTUALLY sometimes it will make migrations twice in a row, without ANY changes to the code!

Comment: To clarify, Gershom's last comment actually applies to a different field, which works exactly the same way as the field in the example above. It makes migrations for that one field hundreds of times in a row.

Comment: Are you sure `pytz.common_timezones`? Not `pytz.common_timezones_set`? My guess is that `TIMEZONE_CHOICES` changes somehow. Try to extract `choices=[...]` from migration files (maybe by hand) and compare them.

Comment: What version of pytz are you using?

Comment: `2015.4` I think? Does that make sense?

Comment: You can use `pip freeze` to make sure the version is consistent. Between version `2015.4` and `2015.7` a new timezone `America/Fort_Nelson` was added. Could you just leave a comment again when you know for sure the `pytz` version you're using?

Comment: Definitely `2015.4`, but this is a collaborative project with other developers who may have made migrations using an updated version of `pytz`!

Comment: Just to confirm what you wrote, can you put an extract of the migration file where the field is reset?

Comment: Just compared values for the `choices` field between the migrations - the values ARE different! The differences appear far down the list, so I missed them. Django was CORRECTLY detecting migrations because my `pytz` has a different list of timezones when compared to my colleague's `pytz`.

Comment: Alright! Maybe answer your question then, it could help someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an existing package that will allow you to use a time zone directly as a model field.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-timezone-field/

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    timezone1 = TimeZoneField(default='Europe/London') # defaults supported
```

Comment: Considering that we figured out the true cause of the problem within the comments, this is a good solution that fixes the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy the plain list of timezones from `pytz` to your project, so you are sure that choices does not depends from a third party

Comment: I must say I'm not sure if I like this solution, because I'd prefer to keep up to date with `pytz`'s evolving list of timezones. I think a better solution would simply be to update `pytz`.

Answer (score 0):

Your timezones are probably coming out in different orders on different runs. Try

```
import pytz
TIMEZONE_CHOICES = ()
for time_zone in pytz.common_timezones:
    TIMEZONE_CHOICES += ((time_zone, time_zone),)
TIMEZONE_CHOICES = sorted(TIMEZONE_CHOICES) # sort list to make it consistent
```

Also--a minor nit since this only runs at startup--but building up a big tuple with repeated concatenation is probably a lot more expensive than this

```
import pytz
TIMEZONE_CHOICES = sorted((tz,tz) for tz in pytz.common_timezones)
```